# In angular 2 , how to hide side nav bar in some components

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to hide side nav bar in login component. but it's not hiding.
I am created the side nav service,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SidenavService {

 visible: boolean;

  constructor() {this.visible = false; }
   hide() { this.visible = false; }

  show() { this.visible = true; }

  toggle() { this.visible = !this.visible; }

}
```

In side nav html:

```
<nav class="main-menu" style="margin-top:50px;  position: fixed; background-color:#163648;">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="home">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-2x"></i>
        <span class="nav-text">home</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-subnav">
      <a routerLink="user">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i>
        <span class="nav-text">Users</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

In side.ts:

```
isIn = false;
toggleState() {
  let bool = this.isIn;
  this.isIn = bool === false ? true : false;
}
@ViewChild('childModal') childModal: SidenavComponent;
constructor(private router: Router, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, public sidenav: SidenavService) {

}
```

Comment: The code you have provided will not hide anything - I don't see how its supposed to work. You have no `HTML` or `CSS` that even mention hiding. You inject your service but don't do anything with it? - what is `the toggleState()` method actually controlling ? `isIn` bool isn't used in your template to control any visibility or anything.

Answer (score 0):

In the parent of `side.ts` - you should have a boolean that controls the visibility of the sidenav.

`isSideNavDisplay: boolean = true;`

You can then **inject your service into this constructor**.

```
constructor(public sidenav: SidenavService){}
```

Then from here you have several approaches - **Observables** , **onChanges** ,**public statics** *not advised*

I will explain one method (**and my preferred choice)**
You should redesign your service to contain a `BehaviourSubject<boolean>` that will publish the visibility state to all its subscribers.

### This is useful because you can toggle visibility of the sidebar from any component in your application

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviourSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SidenavService {


  $visible: BehaviourSubject<boolean>;

  visible: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.visible = false; 

    $visible = new BehaviourSubject(false);


  }

  getVisibilityStream(){
    return this.$visible;
  }

  hide() { 
    this.visible = false;
    this.$visible.next(this.visible);
  }

  show() { 
    this.visible = true;
    this.$visible.next(this.visible);
  }

  toggle() { 
    this.visible = !this.visible; 
    this.$visible.next(this.visible);
  }

    }
```

In your parent component (the parent of side.ts) you will need to subscribe to this service as soon as you inject it.

```
constructor(public sidenav: SidenavService){
    sidenav.getVisibilityStream().subscribe(visible => isSideNavDisplay = visible);
}
```

And in your parent template:

`<sidenav *ngIf="isSideNavDisplay"></sidenav>`

Simply inject the service and call any of the publicly exposed methods `toggle()` `hide()` or `show()`